# setup properly Google Tag Manager on Nextjs with dataLayer?

Tags: google-tag-manager, next.js

### What I have

My `_document` file:

```js
import NextDocument, { Head } from 'next/document';

const GTM_TRACKING_ID = 'GTM-ID';

class WebAppDocument extends NextDocument {
  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="es">
        <Head>

          { /* Global Tag Manager (gtm.js) */}
          { /* => load GTM scripts according to environment variable */ }
          <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []` }} />

          <script
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','${GTM_TRACKING_ID}');
              `,
            }}
          />
        </Head>
      </html>
    );
  }
}
```

My `_app` file:

```js
import NextApp from 'next/app';

const pushEvent = ({ event, pagePath, pageTitle }) => {
  window.dataLayer.push({
    event,
    pagePath,
    pageTitle,
  });
};

class WebApp extends NextApp {
  componentDidMount() {
    // push data to Google Tag Manager
    pushEvent({
      event: 'PageView',
      pagePath: window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash,
      pageTitle: document.title,
    });
  }
}
```

### What I want

1. I've seen the [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-google-analytics/pages/_app.js) and used `Router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', url => dataLayer.push({}))` to execute `dataLayer`. Is this the best approach? Or is it better to run the code to populate the `dataLayer` in `componentDidMount`.
2. I want to load GTM scripts according to environment variable. How could this be achieved?